# What's a word like "disregard" or "bypass" that means "hides"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine that someone skips a step, with the hope that the audience will never know that it existed.  I was thinking *extends* or *circumvents*.  I'm not sure if these words are on the nose; I am looking for a word that really shows intent to conceal.

Here's a sample sentence:

> Any plan of action that ______ preservation of human life is, at its core, flawed.

Comment: *wilfully neglects*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think ***eschew*** would fit well in these circumstances.

Comment: Yes, that sounds lovely.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like there is a perfect term lurking at the edge of my memory, but all I'm coming up with immediately is "Ignore" in the sense of pretending that something does not exist.

"Gloss Over" is a bit better, and plain old "Overlook" is another possibility.

Comment: That's how I feel, also, Mickeyf.  There's this theory about tip-of-the-tongue memory, that it's a weakening of the connection between the sound of a word and the meaning of the word?  I think it's actually a strengthening because a) we're trying, and b) it often happens to me when I'm trying to put a word into a new context.

Comment: Maybe obliviate or omit.  Circumvent sounds strongest.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't quite work (gracefully) in your sample sentence, *elide* is a word that describes the kind of action you mention in your opening sentence.

From my Merriam-Webster thesaurus:

> Entry Word: **elide** Function: verb Text: Synonyms NEGLECT, discount,
>   disregard, fail, forget, ignore, omit, overlook, pass, slight

Comment: Interesting.  Apparently an elide is also an omission of a sound from a word.  For example, "com-fOr-tA-ble" -> "com-fter-ble".

Comment: I'm not certain that elide is the word.  I have to consider the specific context, actually.  As far as I can see, eliding implies a covert slurring together of ideas, resulting in a loaded fact.  I'm thinking of con men.  They sell salvation, implying that their victims' current situation is hopeless.  They ask people to believe, but they conceal/'elide' the method by which they will bring the salvation.  An excluded method is at the heart of a convincing lie, and when a con man's method comes out, people become defensive and often give things away.  If so, do con men elide their methods?

Comment: Straying off topic, but the Moist Lipwig books ("Going Postal", "Making Money") in Terry Pratchett's Discworld series have some insightful discussions of the heart of the mechanism by which people are conned.

Answer (score 1):

To *obscure* is to conceal, to make unclear or indistinct. The act of obscuring is an intention to hide or make less visible. However, in the context of your sentence the word *disregards* is perhaps more appropriate although it doesn't retain the intent of concealing.

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss.  In your case, dismisses.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Ron, citing a dictionary or some other reference work would add value to your answer.